# Add entry to FAQ to discourage link-and-run?

Tags: discussion

So, if the SE sites discourage link-and-run (or rather, encourage down-voting of LAR answers), why isn't this in the FAQ?

Earlier Meta discussions, showing that LAR is discouraged.
[Statistics: Current Ratio of "Link-And-Run" on the Stack Exchange Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38001/statistics-current-ratio-of-link-and-run-on-the-stack-exchange-network)

[Reduce posting of "linking hit-and-runs" answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37968/reduce-posting-of-linking-hit-and-runs-answers)

Example of me assuming that such was in the FAQ, and now looking like a jerk (possibly because I'm a jerk.)

[Publish jpg file as a ScreenSaver via GPO](https://serverfault.com/questions/394762/publish-jpg-file-as-a-screensaver-via-gpo)

Edit - I'm a silly man. This is actually in the FAQ, but you have to expand one of the answers. https://serverfault.com/faq#deletion

Answer (score 6):

[This is a general reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) for link and run. I really don't think it warrants an entry in the faq, they are poor answers and we have the tools to deal with them.

- Down vote it as a poor answer, and leave a comment, this is the one I generally use

> We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This ensures that the answer will remain available even if the link goes dead. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

- Flag it as not an answer.

I'm more than happy to downvote, leave a comment and delete after the OP has had an opportunity to rectify the situation. I'm sure other mods are too.

Comment: Hm - from following a link in those links , I see that this is part of the SO FAQ specifically. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7652/should-the-official-faq-include-information-on-how-to-answer-as-well-as-ask-ques

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

Comment: Reading fail on my part. Editing my question.

Answer (score 3):

Given all the trouble we went through, twice, to come up with the present FAQ and taking into consideration what was eventually *not* included I don't think this issue is serious enough to warrant an entry. I also doubt anyone is quite ready to go through the rewrite process again just yet.

OTOH, it might be worth a running question to discuss what might be included next time. That way we benefit from thought being put into it over a more extended time period. Remember that last time there were a bunch of suggestions when it was already too late.

Comment: I wasn't part of the discussion last time, so I'm not aware of the history. Link? I'm not sure if I should look for that stuff on the SO meta or on this one.

Comment: Edited - It was already in the FAQ, but not visible without expanding a section

Comment: @mfinni Re: the last FAQ rewrite, [see these search results](http://meta.serverfault.com/search?q=%22FAQ+rewrite%22&submit=search)