# Editing posts to change bare URLs to meaningful link text

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I often edit posts (by other people) to change links from something like this<sup>1</sup>:

> I'm ne to lxc, but have 2 instances now happily using these instructions:
>   http://blog.foaa.de/2010/05/lxc-on-debian-squeeze/

To this:

> I'm ne to lxc, but have 2 instances now happily using [these instructions](http://blog.foaa.de/2010/05/lxc-on-debian-squeeze/).

i.e. specifying the link text instead of displaying the URL. Personally I find this form much neater and easier to read.

Should I be doing this though, or is this considered petty editing?

1. Yes, I would also fix the spelling and grammar; just leaving it here because it's not pertinent.

Comment: I do this, frequently. Never had any mods correct me.

Comment: Make sure you remove any URL shorteners you run across too. =]

Comment: That isn't a great example as it's effectively [link and run](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3360/add-entry-to-faq-to-discourage-link-and-run) which we also discourage.

Comment: @Iain Agreed; it just happened to be the one I was looking at when I thought I should ask about this :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fix these, but generally only when I'm in there fixing something *else*. It makes things so much nicer to read though, so I would never roll back an edit that fixed that.

Comment: I would only add please don't fix old questions unless they're particularly awful links (or particularly good questions) -- Edits still bump questions to the front page...

Comment: @voretaq7 Old questions are still read by people. Why are new questions more important than old ones? And why is bumping to the front page a bad thing if you don't do it to a lot of posts at once?

Comment: @svick A lot of old questions don't generate the views that warrant much effort in fixing them - at least in my opinion. Of course if you have a 100+ views/day question fixing it is a Good Thing, but something that gets viewed once or twice a month and is otherwise excellent except for an ugly URL can probably be left alone. (URL shorteners are a different matter - kill these with fire so when bit.ly shuts down we don't lose our links :)

Comment: @svick Note also that my problem is not with fixing the old question as long as it's done in moderation, I'd just prefer not to see a *lot* of old questions pushing new ones down -- While not quite as high as Stack Overflow our question volume is such that the lower down the list of new questions you are the less likely you are to get a timely answer...

Comment: Exactly @voretaq7, the older posts going to the top just degrades the signal-noise ratio and encourages silly resurrections of old posts, that is the non-observant poster answering questions from 4 years ago. ;-)

Comment: @svick, maybe the solution is altering the front page algorithm to only look at substantive changes.

Comment: @Somantra Accurately detecting "substantive" is an NP-Complete (or at least NP-Hard) problem, but I'm sure as soon as the Stack Exchange developers master natural language processing and the heuristic algorithms to detect substantive changes they'll implement them :-) (The usual alternative of "% changed" breaks on posts with awful spelling/grammar: I could have a 30-50% delta but have made zero substantive changes)

Comment: @voretaq7, in the absence of SE natural language mastery, a self-reported non-substantive edit disposition might do the trick. :-)

Comment: @Somantra My former life as a software developer has lead me to never trust users. ***ESPECIALLY*** when I'm the user... now if you'll excuse me there's a [jolly red candy like button](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jjN-H62U64) that I simply *MUST* press :-D

Comment: @voretaq7 So you trust the users enough to make any edit to any post (after they earned it), but you don't trust them to report whether the edit was minor or not?